# Memory Access using 32 bit address in a word-addressable system

Tags: memory, computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm just checking to make sure I have a proper understanding of how memory access works.

Say I have a word-addressable memory system with 64-bit words.
How much memory could be accessed using a 32-bit address size?

A 64 bit word is 8 bytes, so we're dealing with an 8 byte word.
An 8 byte word can hold up to 2^8 (256).

Given that we have a 32 bit address, we have 2^32, but since each word is taking up 256 of those, (2^32)/256 = 1677216 bytes.

To put that into metric terms, we have 2^24 = (2^4) * (2^20) = 16 Mb.

Is this the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Values don't "take up" address space. You've got 2^32 mailboxes, with 64 on/off switches stored in each of them. How many switches have you got in total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 32 bit address provides 4,294,967,296 possible addresses. If the smallest addressable element is a 64 bit == 8 byte word (versus a byte), then the total amount of addressable space would be 4,294,967,296 x 8 = 34,359,738,368 bytes= 34GB.

As for the capacity of an 8 byte word, it's 8 bytes, not 2^8 = 256 bytes.

Note some old computers did have a basic addressing system that only addressed words. Byte accessing required a byte index or offset from a word based address. I don't think any current computers use such a scheme.

Comment: I know this is a different question, just checking to see if I understand what you were saying in reverse.
So if each word is 64 bits, how many address bits are needed for 512 Mb?

Is it 512mb = 2^29, so 2^29/ 8 = 2^26 bits needed?

Comment: @JeffreyDilley -  Mb usually means mega-bits, did you mean  MB - mega bytes? Assuming MB, each address represents 8 bytes so for 512MB, you would need 512MB/8 = 2^9 (512) x 2^20 (mega byte) / 2^3 (8 bytes per word) = 2^(9+20-3) = 2^26 = 67,108,864 addresses, or a 26 bit address.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking 32 bit address which means 2^32 bits can be addressed but if you want how many bytes can be address then just divide it like 2^32/8=2^29 because 1 byte have 8 bit
and if you want how many words can be addressed then 2^29/8 because 1 word contains 8 bytes so 2^26 words can be addressed.

And since one word is 8 byte so we can address (2^26)*8 bytes.
Hope it might help!

Comment: *which means 2^32 bits can be addressed* Nope, it means you have 2^32 different addresses, each of which can hold a whole word, not just a single bit.  Your answer would be correct if your total memory size was 2^32 bits (2^29 byte = 512MiB), but that's not what the question says.